# Subscription - "This subscription will not be automatically renew" Text shown while launching billing flow

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

Subscription launch billing flow bottom sheet shows text that "This subscription will not automatically renew"[image]

Answer (score 1):

Plz skim this article

After trying whole day I got this to my eyes.
As per latest update from Goggle auto-renew, redeems, intro prices, grace periods are paused in India due to some dealing with RBI.

https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.xda-developers.com/google-play-suspend-free-trials-auto-renewing-subscriptions/amp/